# Reducibility of a rational polynomial with two identically complex root

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $n\geq 2$, $f(x)$ is a rational polynomial with degree $n$, and $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ are the complex roots of $f(x)$. If exists $1\leq i<j\leq n, x_i=x_j$, show that $f(x)$ is reducible in $\Bbb Q$.

**My attempt**: Argue by contradition. We assume $$f(x)=(x-x_i)^2(x-\bar x_i)^2g(x)$$ for some $x_i\in\Bbb C$ and $g(x)$ is a real polynomial. Then $f$ is reducible in $\Bbb R$.

What to do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** consider $f'$ and $\mathbf{gcd}_{\Bbb R[X]}(f,f')$. Now, both $f$ and $f'$ are in $\Bbb Q[X]$, so what does that tell you about $\mathbf{gcd}_{\Bbb Q[X]}(f,f')$?

*Remark.* Recall that the *derivative* of a polynomial $f = a_0+a_1x+ \ldots a_n x^n$ is
$$
f' := a_1+2a_2x + \ldots + na_n x^{n-1}
$$

Here's a general fact about derivatives and multiple roots over $\Bbb Q$. Everything that follows can be made more general, but let's stick with polynomials over $\Bbb Q$ for a moment.

Note that "algebraic derivatives" as defined above still satisfy the usual rules $(f+g)' = f'+g'$ and $(fg)' = f'g'$. You can prove this inspecting the coefficients at both sides. Here is a characterization of double roots in terms of derivatives:

**Lemma.** The following are equivalent,

- $\alpha \in \Bbb C$ is a double root of $f$.
- $\alpha$ is a root of $f'$ and $f$.

*Proof.* If $(X-\alpha)^2$ divides $f$ in $\Bbb C$, then $f = (X-\alpha)^2 g$ and taking derivatives we see that $$f' = (X-\alpha)^2 g' + 2(X-\alpha)g$$ is divisible by $X-\alpha$, hence $f'(\alpha) = 0$. Reciprocally, if $f'(\alpha) = 0$ dividing $f$ by $(X-\alpha)^2$ we get

$$
f = (X-\alpha)^2 q + r \tag{1}
$$

with $r = 0$ or $\deg r \leq 1$. and taking derivatives,

$$
f' = (X-\alpha)^2q' + 2(X-\alpha)q + r'
$$
hence evaluating at $\alpha$ yields $0 = f'(\alpha) = r'(\alpha)$. By degree considerations on $r$ it must be $r' = 0$, hence $r$ is constant. Evaluating at $(1)$ gives then $0 = f(\alpha) = r(\alpha)$ and thus $r = 0$, as desired. $\square$

Now, a double root $\alpha$ of $f$ is a common root of $f'$ and $f$, hence $X-\alpha \mid \mathbf{gdc}_{\Bbb C[X]}(f,f')$.

Note that $f$ and $f'$ are polynomials in $\Bbb Q[X]$ and $\Bbb C[X]$ and in both rings one can consider their greatest common divisor. If a polynomial divides both $f$ and $f'$ in $\Bbb Q[X]$, so it does over $\Bbb C[X]$. In particular $\mathbf{gdc}_{\Bbb Q[X]}(f,f') \mid f,f'$ in $\Bbb C[X]$ and so $\mathbf{gdc}_{\Bbb Q[X]}(f,f') \mid \mathbf{gdc}_{\Bbb C[X]}(f,f')$.

However, since there exists $g,h \in \Bbb Q[X]$ for which $\mathbf{gdc}_{\Bbb Q[X]}(f,f') = fg+f'h$ and $\mathbf{gdc}_{\Bbb C[X]}(f,f')$ divides both factors, we get the other division, hence

$$
\mathbf{gdc}_{\Bbb C[X]}(f,f') = \mathbf{gdc}_{\Bbb Q[X]}(f,f') =: (f,f').
$$

In particular, the former was already in $\Bbb Q [X]$. By the lemma, the polynomial $f$ has no double roots if and only if $(f,f') = 1$. In particular $f$ has no double roots if it is irreducible (here we use that $f'\neq 0$, essentially the same argument can be made in any field of characteristic zero). The contrapositive is what you needed.

Comment: What to do then?

Comment: Have you computed $f'$ and $\mathbf{gdc}(f,f')$?

Comment: I do not know how to do next. ...I am sorry.

Comment: @xldd there is nothing to be sorry about!!! I will add a complete solution.

Comment: @xldd There. I encourage you to think about each statement before reading the proof. Please do ask if anything is unclear.